# Find documents that include one of a list of words in R

Tags: r, text, stringr, tidytext

I have two dataframes: `msnbc` contains a column of news transcripts called `text` and `dictionary` contains a column of words called `search`. I want to return a new dataframe that includes all rows of `msnbc` where the `text` field contains one or more words from the `search` column. Toy data:

```
msnbc <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), text=c("hello world", "goodbye world","hello friends"))
dictionary <- data.frame(search=c("hello","lorem","ipsum","dolor")
```

The new dataset should include the first and third element of `msnbc` because they include one of the words from `dictionary$search`

My first thought was to use `str_detect` but there is no option for passing a vector of strings as the pattern. My other idea was to use `filter` somehow but not sure how to implement:

```
new_msnbc <- msnbc %>%
    filter(dictionary$search %in% text)
```

But this doesn't work as intended. What is the best way to do this? Bonus points for a `tidyverse` solution.

Comment: try `grepl` for things like this. `%in%` is not the correct operator.

Comment: grepl doesn't take a vector of strings, only a regex pattern or a single string. I thought there might be a solution that allows a character vector as the pattern for matching.

Comment: Yes, so concatenate them together. https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you can do this with `filter` and `grepl`:

```
result <- msnbc %>%
filter(grepl(paste(dictionary$search, collapse="|"), text))
```